# Dynamic forms in Yii

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii

This is my first project with yi. This is a part of the db model:

```
 table       columns 
 iteration   [id,name,description]
 activity    [id,iteration_id,name,description,duration]
```

So for planning the activities in an iteration my idea is to print a table with the columns

```
[name,description,duration]
```

with 1 row by default (required) and a button for adding new rows to the table.

I've found [THIS](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table) tuto for collecting the tabular input. Now I just need to implement the dynamic part. How can I do it? Does yii have something for helping with this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I guess Yii haven't something for helping you with this task so far. Maybe there are some extensions, but I always made this myself using jQuery.